# Android gradle sync error-Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I recently installed android studio 2.1.2 and I am getting this error:

```
Error:Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip'.
```

I used to have 1.3.1 previously but I opened it recently after a while and it was showing the same error so I decided to do a fresh installation but the error persists.

Here is what the `build.gradle` file looks like for the app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sanchitverma.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please edit your question to fix the formatting of file? Would be greatly appreciated by possible answerers

Comment: Are you able to run Gradle from the command line in that directory?